# Very slow network file transfers

Tags: networking

For some reason, our network is very very slow when it comes to transferring files internally thru LAN (gig).

Some numbers:

```
C:\iperf-2.0.5-3-win32>iperf.exe -c 192.168.100.12 -w 256k
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.100.12, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  256 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.100.73 port 36705 connected with 192.168.100.12 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   385 MBytes   323 Mbits/sec
```

That's from a physical Windows 7 to a virtual Windows Server 2012R2.

Reverse (from the same virtual Windows Server 2012 R2 to the same physical Windows 7) isn't much better, if at all:

```
C:\Users\U1\Desktop\iperf-2.0.5-3-win32>iperf.exe -c 192.168.100.73 -w 256k

------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.100.73, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  256 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.100.12 port 25464 connected with 192.168.100.73 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   431 MBytes   361 Mbits/sec
```

Another test:

```
C:\Users\U1>robocopy \\cd2012\d$ c:\temp dummy*.txt

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Herramienta para copia eficaz de archivos

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Inicio: Wed Apr 08 20:58:57 2015

   Origen : \\cd2012\d$\
     Destino : c:\temp\

    Archivos: dummy*.txt

  Opciones: /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           1    \\cd2012\d$\
100%        Nuevo arch                   537.0 m        dummy.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total   Copiado   OmitidoNo coincidencia     ERROR    Extras
Directorios:         1         0         1         0         0         0
 Archivos:         1         1         0         0         0         0
    Bytes:  537.00 m  537.00 m         0         0         0         0
    Veces:   0:00:16   0:00:16                       0:00:00   0:00:00


Velocidad:            33409594 Bytes/s
Velocidad:            1911.712 Megabytes/min

Finalizado: Wed Apr 08 20:59:14 2015
```

Shows similar results.

I did this when no PCs were on and noone else was in the office using bandwidth. At best, WSUS. Tried it this morning as well and basically same thing happened.

The issue is that but the bigger issue here is how exactly to go on troubleshooting.

Wireshark comes to mind but personally I admit, I do not have enough technical knowledge to view Wireshark and see exactly what is happening. I would need some kind of guidelines and filter tips to know what to put in filter and what to look at exactly so I can watch out for certain flags and know where it is coming from.

Ive also thought about limiting all connections except from my PC and see if it is a PC with some kind of spyware sucking up all the internal bandwidth.

I've checked for rouge DHCP servers and as far as I see, there are none on the network.

The logical choice would be to unplug EVERYTHING from the network and work my way plugging back in but for a business the downtime is very costly so that's why slowing the network down came as a idea.

Any tips on what to do and what not to do?

Answer (score 4):

Network performance problems rarely are a simple thing to diagnose, especially when virtual hardware is thrown in the mix. Let's try to isolate the weak spot...

1) **use iperf to measure a PC to PC connection:** in this manner, you will exclude any virtualizer-related problem. If the results are satisfactory, proceed with step 2. If not, repeat that same test with another 2 PCs with different networking hardware. If the bandwidth is OK, then you have a problem with your first PC. If not, you probably have a switching problem.

2) **use iperf to measure a PC to virtualizer connection:** now let's examine the connection between your PC and the physical virtualizer server. If the results are OK, then network connection between your PC and the server itself is not the problem. Proceed with step 3.

3) if the PC-to-Server connection is OK but PC-to-VM is slow, probably the culprit is the virtual adapter. **If you can, use a paravirtualized network adapter/driver** for your virtual W2012 installation. [The difference can really be big](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/virtualization/42-kvm-virtio-paravirtualized-drivers-why-they-matter.html?start=3)

Comment: WOW, I think you are right....I think it is a driver issue. Im hitting the Hyper-V host at a decent speed while Im hitting the Hyper-V guest at the speeds I mentioned. How do I change to paravirtualized drivers on my network card inside that WS2012R2 guest? Should I do the same for the PERC H730 Mini?

Comment: Found this: http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/ Would I just mount this in WS2012R2 and replace my network and disk controllers with everything inside this CD?

Comment: The drivers you posted are for Linux/KVM hypervisor. As you are using Hyper-V, you had to install the appropriate drivers.

Comment: Im not sure if I follow. What paravirtualized drivers should I use when using a Hyper-V 2012 R2 host and a Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V 2012 R2 guest?

Comment: After reading on technet, it seems that Windows 2008 and laters [already ships with the relevant drivers in-place](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/68545135-3cd2-4512-be93-23917b6a9a29/what-versions-of-the-windows-servers-support-paravirtualization?forum=winserverhyperv) So I am not sure why your network throughput is so low when communicating with the guest VM. One possible explanation is related to [VMQ (hardware queues) and their use by the host/guest system](http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2k7jn5/after_2_years_i_have_finally_solved_my_slow/)

Comment: After all, it seems a quite common issue with VMQ. [See here for another example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/999f218d-e8f9-42de-ab82-3d22bd5b67e9/hyperv-and-very-slow-network?forum=winserverhyperv)

Comment: I disabled VMQ but didnt see any difference. Tried also playing around with Ethernet@Wirespeed but nothing.